# Разбить строку в массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, строки

```
$dir = 'update';
$path = 'update';
$dir = opendir ("$path");
$i = 0;
while (false !== ($file =  readdir($dir))){
    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
        if (strpos($file, '.csv',1) ) {  
            $i++; 
        }
        if ( substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.csv',1) ) ) {
            $res_str = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.csv',1) );
            $arr1 = str_split($file, 18); // преобразует строку в массив
            print_r($arr1);
            //$arr1 = explode (" ", $file);

        }
    }
}
```

Такой вопрос как разбить строку в массив, чтобы идентификатор увеличивался? В данном случае у меня выводит:

```
Array ( [0] => 10.20.138.0,23.csv ) 
Array ( [0] => 10.20.139.0,24.csv ) 
Array ( [0] => 10.20.140.0,25.csv )
```

В каталоге 3 файла 10.20.138.0,23.csv, 10.20.139.0,24.csv , 10.20.140.0,25.csv

Answer (score 1):

Вам что-то такое нужно?

```
<?php
$dir = 'update';
$path = 'update';
$res_arr = [];
$dir = opendir ("$path");
$i = 0;
$k = 0;
while (false !== ($file =  readdir($dir))){
    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
        if (strpos($file, '.csv',1) ) {  
            $i++; 
        }
        if ( substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.csv',1) ) ) {
            $res_str = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.csv',1) );
            $arr1 = str_split($file, 18); // преобразует строку в массив
            print_r($arr1);
            $res_arr[$k] = array_values($arr1)[0]; 
            //$arr1 = explode (" ", $file);
            $k++;
        }

    }
}

print_r($res_arr);


Array
(
    [0] => 1.csv
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.csv
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.csv
    [1] => 2.csv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$arr1[]` - добавит элемент в конец массива (соответственно, идентификатор увеличится)

Answer (score -1):

Есть такая функция в php `explode()`

http://www.php.su/explode()